# How to write to the pasteboard with NSFilePromiseProvider

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag, nsfilepromiseprovider

I'm trying to support multi-item dragging with `NSTableView` and `NSCollectionView` using the new `NSPasteboardWriting` APIs. In my real app, I have dragging working for my table view, but not for my collection view (the `NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate` methods never get called). When I tried building a demo app from the ground up, I was able to reproduce this with an `NSTableView`.

I've set breakpoints inside both methods of `DragDelegate`, and neither gets called. `-tableView:pasteboardWriterForRow:` does get called, though. When I drag outside the app, I see the row's image attached to the cursor, but as far as Finder is concerned, there are no files on the pasteboard. There's no option to drop onto the Dock or a Finder window.

An instance of `CollectionController` is set as my table view's `dataSource`. It has a single column, whose text label is bound to the represented object (since it's just an `NSString`). I'm running Xcode 10.0 on Mojave 10.14.0. Here are the classes I have:

## CollectionController

```
@interface CollectionController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource>

@property (strong) id<NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate> dragDelegate;

@end

@implementation CollectionController

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
            row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return @"Test string";
}

- (id<NSPasteboardWriting>)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView pasteboardWriterForRow:(NSInteger)row {
    self.dragDelegate = [[DragDelegate alloc] init];
    return [[NSFilePromiseProvider alloc] initWithFileType:@"public.text"
                                                  delegate:self.dragDelegate];

    return prov;
}

@end
```

## DragDelegate

```
@interface DragDelegate: NSObject <NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate>

@end

@implementation DragDelegate

- (NSString *)filePromiseProvider:(NSFilePromiseProvider *)filePromiseProvider
                  fileNameForType:(NSString *)fileType
{
    return @"file.txt";
}

- (void)filePromiseProvider:(NSFilePromiseProvider *)filePromiseProvider
          writePromiseToURL:(NSURL *)url
          completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
    NSData *data = [@"test file contents" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [data writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
    completionHandler(nil);
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you call `setDraggingSourceOperationMask:forLocal:`?

Comment: @Willeke Nope! And that's the problem, which fixed my issue with my NSCollectionView in my real app. But I can't figure out why it's working for the NSTableView in my real app without making that call...

Comment: @Willeke if you post that suggestion as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default dragging operation with

```
 - (void)setDraggingSourceOperationMask:(NSDragOperation)mask forLocal:(BOOL)isLocal;
```